# Override all log4j.properties for webapps in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

i'm running Apache Tomcat 7.0.59 on a OpenSuse Leap 42.2 with Java 1.8.0_65 and have several webapplications deployed. Some of them are my own, and some of them are third-party.

Some webapps come with a log4j.properties file in their classpath. Now i want to have one global log4j.properties file which overrides all others so i can aggregate all logging information into one big my-tomcat.log file.

What i did was add the VM flag -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/my/custom-log4j.properties to tomcat's setenv.sh file which basically works great. Now i have my own my-tomcat.log file which contains all logging information.

But here is the problem: the "old" log files are still written. It seems that log4j is still reading all the app-specific log4j.properties files.

for example my custom-log4j.properties file looks like this:

```
# Set root logger level to error
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, File


###### Console appender definition #######

# All outputs currently set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# use log4j NDC to replace %x with tenant domain / username
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %x %-5p [%c{3}] [%t] %m%n 
#log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c] %m%n

###### File appender definition #######
log4j.appender.File.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.File=eWork.log
log4j.appender.File.Append=true
log4j.appender.File.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c] [%t] %m%n
```

One of my webapps logging files looks like this:

```
# Set root logger level to error
log4j.rootLogger=error, Console, File

###### Console appender definition #######

# All outputs currently set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# use log4j NDC to replace %x with tenant domain / username
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %x %-5p [%c{3}] [%t] %m%n 
#log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c] %m%n

###### File appender definition #######
log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.File=alfresco.log
log4j.appender.File.Append=true
log4j.appender.File.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c] [%t] %m%n
```

both my-tomcat.log as well as alfresco.log are created. Also the catalina.out file is written although i have not added the console appender in my custom-log4j.properties. However the contents of catalina.out is quite small.

Do you have any ideas how to completely override any log4j.properties files from all webapps?

Thank you very much for any help and have a nice day!

Comment: Where is your log4j JAR file located? `catalina.out` cannot be avoided, since that is where the process's `stdout` stream goes.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Every webapp has its own log4j jar.

Comment: If you package log4j with each application, they will all initialize independently and won't work together.

Comment: @mesx did you find a workaround?